# Remove nodes in xml

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml, xslt

I want to delete one node whit "KG01_Personnummer" string. and then save it to StringReader, having problem to get this to work.

I have tried many things! Plz help

```
public string ConvertXmlToHtml(string xmlCode)
{
    doc.LoadXml(xmlCode);

    foreach(XmlNode elem in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (elem.Name.Contains("KG01_SSN"))
        {
            elem.RemoveChild(elem);
        }
    }
    xmlCode = doc.ToString();      

    var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xsltCodeWhitClass));
    xslCompiledTransform.Load(reader);
    var xmlRead = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlCode));

    using (stringWriter)
    {
        xslCompiledTransform.Transform((XmlReader)xmlRead, emptyArgs, stringWriter);
       return whitelistedHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Upload your XML file

Comment: That node exists before or after processing that XSLT ?

Comment: Try something like this.

XElement root = XElement.Parse(@"<Root>
                                <Child1>
                                    <GrandChild1/>
                                    <GrandChild2/>
                                    <GrandChild3/>
                                </Child1>
                            </Root>");
            root.Element("Child1").Element("GrandChild1").Remove();
            Console.WriteLine(root);

Answer (score 0):

remove xmlCode = doc.ToString();

try

```
using (stringWriter)
{
    xslCompiledTransform.Transform(doc, emptyArgs, stringWriter);
   return whitelistedHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and why it should be used a bit more detailed.